# How can i import class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I define serveral interfaces and classes in **system.d.ts** file.

When I build typescript, It doesn't have any errors. But When I run javascript, It respresent some errors like below.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '{my_dir}/dist/src/types/system' imported from {my_dir}/dist/src/controllers/layoutController.js
```

Interfaces are imported by codes like 'import type ...' But Classes can't.

What is the problem in My code?

How Do I resolve this problem?

**system.d.ts**

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import { estypes } from '@elastic/elasticsearch'

export interface Controller<T> {
  service: Service<T>
  create?(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>
  get?(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>
  getAll?(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>
  update?(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>
  delete?(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>
}

export class BasicController<T> implements Controller<T> {
  #service
  constructor({ service }: { service: Service<T> }) {
    this.#service = service
  }

  get service(): Service<T> {
    return this.#service
  }

  async create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const model: T = req?.body ?? {}
      const createdId: string = await this.#service.create({ model: model })
      res.status(201).send({ createdId })
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }

  async getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const models: { total: number; rows: T[] } = await this.#service.getAll()
      res.status(200).send(models)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }

  async get(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const modelId: string = req?.params?.modelId ?? ''
      const model: T = await this.#service.get({ modelId: modelId })
      res.status(200).send(model)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }

  async update(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const model: T = req?.body ?? { _id: '' }
      const modelId: string = req?.body?._id ?? ''
      await this.#service.update({ modelId: modelId, model: model })
      res.status(204)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }

  async delete(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const modelId: string = req.params.modelId
      await this.service.delete({ modelId: modelId })
      res.status(204)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }
}

export interface Service<T> {
  name?: string
  create?({ model }: { model: T }): Promise<string>
  get?({ modelId }: { modelId: string }): Promise<T>
  getAll?(): Promise<{ total: number; rows: T[] }>
  update?({ modelId, model }: { modelId: string; model: T }): Promise<void>
  delete?({ modelId }: { modelId: string }): Promise<void>
}

export class BasicService<T> implements Service<T> {
  async create({ model }: { model: T }): Promise<string> {
    const { _id } = await global.app.elasticClient.index({ index: 'signage-server', body: model })
    return _id
  }

  async getAll(): Promise<{ total: number; rows: T[] }> {
    const results: { total: number; rows: T[] } = await global.app.elasticClient.search({ index: 'signage-server', query: { match_all: {} }, size: 10000 })
    return results
  }

  async get({ modelId }: { modelId: string }): Promise<T> {
    const model: T = await global.app.elasticClient.get({ index: 'signage-server', id: modelId })
    return model
  }
  async update({ modelId, model }: { modelId: string; model: T }): Promise<void> {
    await global.app.elasticClient.update({ index: 'signage-server', id: modelId, body: { doc: model } })
  }

  async delete({ modelId }: { modelId: string }): Promise<void> {
    await global.app.elasticClient.delete({ index: 'signage-server', id: modelId })
  }

  async search({ query }: { query: estypes.QueryDslQueryContainer }): Promise<{ total: number; rows: T[] }> {
    const results: { total: number; rows: T[] } = await global.app.elasticClient.search({ index: 'signage-server', query, size: 10000 })
    return results
  }
}

export interface SetupService<T> extends Service<T> {
  connectPlayer({ player }: { player: T }): Promise<string>
  approvePlayer({ player }: { player: T }): Promise<void>
}

export interface DBClient<T> {
  client: T
}
```

**layoutController.ts**

```js
import layoutService from '../services/layoutService.js'
import { BasicController } from '../types/system'

export default new BasicController({ service: layoutService })
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: `system.d.ts` `.d.ts` files are only for declaring types, not doing actual implementations. Did you mean to do `system.ts`?

Comment: My interfaces and classes are declared in system.d.ts file. and I implement actual code in layoutController.ts file.

Comment: `My interfaces and classes are declared in system.d.ts file` The BasicController and BasicService classes are implementations (in addition to being types). If you want to be able to import that code, put it in a `.ts` file, not `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Thank you for replying my answer!!!. Your answer is very helpful!!.  I read typescript docs about class module. Can I use class with module?

Comment: Yes you can do `export class Bla` and then `import { Bla } from "./myfile.ts"` later.